# With Quarkus, how do I build a native image in a docker image (with Kotlin and Gradle)

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

The Quarkus documentation explains how to build a docker image using Maven. But I'm using Gradle and Kotlin. I'm trying to figure out how to do these steps:

```
FROM quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:19.2.1 AS build
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
USER root
RUN chown -R quarkus /usr/src/app
USER quarkus
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml -Pnative clean package
```

First, I think I'd want an image that has gradle instead of maven (quay.io doesn't seem to have one). Then I'd have to figure what else I need to copy (instead of pom.xml) Maybe `build.gradle`? `settings.gradle`? `gradle.properties`? Secondly, I believe this image also contains GraalVM. So I'm not sure about what I could do there.

Do I *have* to use Maven? I really, really do not want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the documentation and builer image are tailored towards maven, you can however use Gradle if you do something like:

```
FROM quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:19.2.1 AS build
COPY gradlew /usr/src/app
COPY gradle /usr/src/app
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY build.gradle /usr/src/app
COPY settings.gradle /usr/src/app
USER root
RUN chown -R quarkus /usr/src/app
USER quarkus
RUN ./gradlew build
```

Depending on what your `.dockerignore` contains, you might need to adapt it as well (or just remove it)

Comment: Would `gradle buildNative ` be correct in that context?

Comment: That yields `Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain` That leads me to believe gradle does not exist in this image.

Comment: Oops! I meant that `./gradlew buildNative` should work, not `gradle` :)